PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day 7): Santa’s in a pickle!
This puzzle is part of the Puzzling Stack Exchange Advent Calendar 2024. The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 150 reputation.< Previous Door Next Door >
Seasons Greetings PSE, Santa Claus here and I am in a little bit of a pickle whereby I need this community of very smart and talented people to help me. You see, I was currently delivering my presents as I usually do every year and everything was going plain sailing until I read the list of this particular family! Someone has played a naughty prank as the list of presents has been heavily distorted. To make matter worse, I can’t remember what was asked for! Fortunately, it isn’t too badly messed up. Since this looks like a puzzle to solve and I am not up to the task, I am asking you guys to help me out!
Here is the list:



The ??AK-O Family
Presents




Horatio (Father)
?SIU?C ?A?BB


? (Mother)
L?W?J T ??O


Anatoly (son)
Y?T R?TC ??ITCA


Judit (daughter)
??IR L?S ???F


Vera (baby)
S?AB L?M


Garry (pet)
ST


Family Piano
ST?AHC L



Your mission is to find out the names, presents that I need to give and the culprit needing to be punished before it’s too late!
Hint 1:

 If I recall correctly the family are all very fond of a certain game except for maybe one of them. Also for the pet well he is the sort that likes to hop around…

Hint 2:

 A couple of things… some of the letters may feel like they should be omitted but they have not been only to make the puzzle less difficult. Also one user thought about a horse but while the item would fit a horse think about another hopping pet…

Hint 3

 L _ _ _ _

Hint 4

 The culprit’s name has 6 letters


what kind of family asks for gifts for their piano but doesn't give it a name?

That’s for you to find out

Can I confirm that the father's name is Horatio and not Horacio?

@DanielS definitely Horatio

While we're confirming names -- definitely Judith, not Judit?

Oops my bad yes it is judit

@PDT ... and Gary?

Sorry spelling is a little off mb… I mean it doesn’t matter too much… it wouldn’t affect the solving process I think.

It's on +9-2 right now. No idea who the downvotes are from but any puzzle can get random drive-by downvotes. I'd advise not taking it personally and hope you undelete it -- it looks like an interesting puzzle.

@GarethMcCaughan it’s undeleted.

It occurs to me to wonder: should this have the [knowledge] tag or not? (On the basis of what I've worked out so far it's neither obvious that it should nor obvious that it shouldn't.)

@GarethMcCaughan I was debating with myself whether or not it should be included in the puzzle because for the vast majority of it it isn’t necessary… but now I feel like it should be there…Also feel free to post any progress so far I am curious to know

I'll post a partial just as soon as I've spent a little while thinking whether hint 3 helps me more than hints 1 and 2 did (which it very well might since at the moment I have no idea what it refers to).

(Unless it refers to the piano's present, in which case I might know what it refers to and if so it doesn't tell me anything new. But I think that's unlikely.)

rot13(Pbhyq gur zbgure or Pneby Cnegbș)

First of all, the game they're fond of (see Hint 1) is pretty clearly

 chess.

The names

 are those of famous chess players. Horatio CARO (as in the Caro-Kann opening, and it looks as if CARO-KANN is actually the family name for some reason); Anatoly Karpov (former world champion), Judit Polgar (strongest ever female player), Vera Menchik (an earlier eminent female player), Garry Kasparov (arguably the greatest player of all time). And the piano is probably a Giuoco Piano.

The presents

 are reversed, and have some letters censored and some missing entirely. The entirely-missing letters seem in most (all?) cases to be CAR + one or two others. In comments OP clarifies that the intention is that they're all rough homophones of "cara".

So we have

 Horatio Caro, father: [CARI]BBEAN CRUISE -> eSIUrC nAeBB[]
 ? ?, mother: ONE [CARA]T JEWEL -> LeWeJ T[] enO
 Anatoly Karpov, son: ACTION [CHARA]CTER TOY -> YoT ReTC[] noITCA
 Judit Polgar, daughter: FREE [CAROU]SEL RIDE -> eerF LeS[] edIR
 Vera Menchik, baby: [CARA]MEL BARS -> SrAB LeM[]
 Garry Kasparov, rabbit: [CARRO]TS -> ST[]
 Giuoco? Piano: [CARO]L CHARTS -> STrAHC L[]

Now

it seems like we should look either at the censored letters or at the completely omitted ones that aren't just CAR. It turns out that the latter aren't important, but the former are:
NN     [CAR]O-KAnn
ENRE   [CARI]BBeAn CrUISe
NEEE   One [CARA]T JeWeL
ONO    ACTIon [CHARA]CTER ToY
REEDE  Free [CAROU]SeL RIde
ER     [CARA]MeL BArS
-      [CARRO]TS
R      [CARO]L CHArTS

Now,

 what do those censored letters have in common? They are all instances of D,E,N,O,R. I'd been looking for a culprit in the family, but it turns out it was one of my staff all along: the reindeer DONNER has been messing with the present-lists for some reason and has rather counterproductively tried to hide his tracks by suppressing things that could be part of his name.

As for the mother,

 apparently she is KAREN Asrian (who despite the name is actually male). This was guessed by user39583 and I still have no idea how; I suppose it's relevant that the first name begins with a rough homophone of ‘CARA’, but that's not a thing that was going on with any of the other first names.

Credit where due:

 Florian F and DanielS made suggestions for the daughter's present containing the key word RIDE which I'd completely missed. user39583 somehow figured almost all the last bits out, apparently by magic :-). And PDT, author of the question, kindly confirmed and corrected various things.

Nitpickery:

 I don't really understand why this is the Caro-Kann family rather than just the Caro family. (The Caro-Kann opening is named after two people, Horatio Caro and Marcus Kann.) I don't know how we were supposed to guess that the mother (1) is named after a male chess player and (2) has a first name that begins with something that sounds like "Caro" (a constraint not obeyed by any of the other family members). But evidently guessing that was possible, since user39583 managed to do it, so the fault is clearly mine :-).


I think you're onto something with rot13(crg jbhyq or A) because rot13(xavtugf "ubc" naq fb qb enoovgf)

Ok you are extremely close to completing the puzzle. A few things… firstly cara+o= caro. The pattern is related to homophones. Secondly The daughter’s  present is partly wrong. I will drop a hint later for the culprit extraction. It is way simpler than you think but is maybe a little unorthodox.

rot13(svar evqr) ?

rot13(SNVE PNEBHFRY EVQR)? feels more likely than rot13(SNEQ PNEBHFRY EVQR)

@DanielS You are definitely right about EVQR. Don’t forget the mothers name still needs to be filled in

@Florian F svar is half right.

It feels a stretch, but could the mother by this player?

@DanielS Seems much less famous than all the others so I'm guessing not. But anything's possible :-).

@DanielS your suggestion for the daughter's present sounds much better than mine, though depending on what "half right" means PDT's reply to Florian may mean it's wrong.

Oh, actually, I see PDT replied to you specifically too, so SNVE must be wrong too. I'm not currently seeing a better word to put there than yours... [EDITED to add:] Ah, maybe I have one.

rot13(Gur svefg jbeq bs gur qnhtugre'f tvsg pbhyq or SERR naq gur zbgure'f anzr pbhyq or XNERA/PNEBA. Vs gur phycevg unf jnagrq gb uvqr yrggre'f nccrnevat va gurve anzr, gura vg zvtug cbffvoyl or QBAARE.)

@user39583 yes!!! You deserve a

@GarethMcCaughan I meant that homophones of ‘cara’ can be joined to each of those words that is the pattern.

Also it’s ‘Karen’ following the chess players theme. ‘Karen Asrian’

Butbutbut rot13(Xnera Nfevna vf znyr).

Anyway, all appropriate edits made. I think that's it now?

Yes more or less complete but you are not still not noting the ‘cara’ soundalikes before every word

Also I feel the answer is too messy

I'm not? Looks to me like I did note it explicitly. I'm sorry you find the answer too messy; I personally rather like the stream-of-consciousness style that invites the reader to watch the puzzle being solved, but of course your mileage may vary. I'll polish the answer up a bit and see if it suits your taste better afterwards.
